# Volume cut off from the sphere by the cone using cylindrical polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spheres, cylindrical-coordinates, dual-cone

Find the volume cut off from the sphere ${x^2}+{y^2}+{z^2}={a^2} $ by the cone ${x^2 }+{y^2} ={z^2}$ using cylindrical polar coordinates?

I know there will be a dual cone but I am not able to write the limits in the cylindrical polar form.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Part outside the cone: -$\sqrt{2}$/2<z<$\sqrt{2}/2$; z<r<$\sqrt{a^2-z^2}$

Comment: Way easier in spherical coordinates though

Comment: Since you haven't shown any work, I may be guessing wrong about what you're thinking, but I guess you are thinking to put together a triple integral. You have three variables to integrate over, with six limits. So are you totally stumped on every single one of those limits? That's a very different question from just having some particular doubts about one or two of the limits, and you would get very different answers to those questions. By not actually asking _either_ question, you reduce the chance of getting any answer.